# Concatenate two dataframes based on no of rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes:

```
a b c     d e f
2 4 6     6 7 1
4 7 9     9 5 8
          7 9 6
          5 8 2
```

Now I want to create a new dataframe like this:

```
a b c d e f 
2 4 6 6 7 1 
4 7 9 9 5 8
```

That is, I only want the rows of the second dataframe until the number of rows matches with the first dataframe.

Comment: `df1.join(df2)`

Comment: @user3483203 even better!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`concat` have `join = 'inner'`

```
pd.concat([x,y],join = 'inner', axis=1)
Out[184]: 
   a  b  c  d  e  f
0  2  4  6  6  7  1
1  4  7  9  9  5  8
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
df1=pd.DataFrame({'a': [2, 4], 'b': [4, 7], 'c': [6, 9]})
df2=pd.DataFrame({'d': [6, 9, 7, 5], 'e': [ 7, 5, 9, 8], 'f': [1,8,6, 2]})
result = pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1, join_axes=[df1.index])
print(result)
```

Refer panda documentation. Its really good.Added the link below.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> x = pd.DataFrame({'a': [2, 4], 'b': [4, 7], 'c': [6, 9]})
>>> y = pd.DataFrame({'d': [6, 9, 7, 5], 'e': [ 7, 5, 9, 8], 'f': [1,8,6, 2]})
>>> x
   a  b  c
0  2  4  6
1  4  7  9
>>> y
   d  e  f
0  6  7  1
1  9  5  8
2  7  9  6
3  5  8  2

>>> pd.concat([ x, y], axis=1).dropna()
     a    b    c  d  e  f
0  2.0  4.0  6.0  6  7  1
1  4.0  7.0  9.0  9  5  8
```

Comment: `pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1).dropna().astype(int)` would solve the problem of some values being cast as floats

Answer (score 0):

Using [`pandas.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.concat.html) and **slicing** we can proceed by doing:

```
a = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(2,3)), columns=["a", "b", "c"])
b = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(4,3)), columns=["d", "e", "f"])
```

So the two DataFrames look like:

[image: a]

[image: b]

Then just run:

```
result = pd.concat([a, b[:len(a)]], axis=1)
```

So the result is:

[image: result]

Comment: When one downvotes an answer, it would be nice to explain what is wrong so that the answer may be enhanced.

Comment: @AntonvBR the images are not of code, they are of the DataFrames. The textual output is harder to read on mobile devices.

Answer (score 0):

You can use join to join the dataframes

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [2, 4], 'b': [4, 7], 'c': [6, 9]})
df2= pd.DataFrame({'d': [6, 9, 7, 5], 'e': [ 7, 5, 9, 8], 'f': [1,8,6, 2]})
df1.join(df2)

   a  b  c  d  e  f
0  2  4  6  6  7  1
1  4  7  9  9  5  8
```