# How to make a list for each row of values of two dataframe columns

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns

I have two columns and I would like to create a list for each row. Thus, each list would contain two values; the values of each column for that specific row.
For example:

```
A B
1 2
3 4
5 6
```

I would like to have a list for each row of values i.e. `[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]`

Could you help me with this one please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Concate two dataframes based on no of rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51327984/concate-two-dataframes-based-on-no-of-rows)

Comment: @IgorS this is definitely not a duplicate of that link

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert a row in pandas into list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19585280/convert-a-row-in-pandas-into-list)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this if you want to keep it in a dataframe:

```
df['new'] = df.values.tolist()

>>> df
   A  B     new
0  1  2  [1, 2]
1  3  4  [3, 4]
2  5  6  [5, 6]
```

Otherwise, if you just want the lists, just use:

```
df.values.tolist()

[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
```

Or even just `df.values` (though the result will be a `numpy` array, as opposed to a list of lists):

```
>>> df.values
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [5, 6]])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you had the following DataFrame:

```
print(df)
#   A  B
#0  1  2
#1  3  4
#2  5  6
```

One way to get the rows as lists is by using `to_records()`:

```
print([list(x) for x in df.to_records(index=False)])
#[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
```

Or if you wanted to include the index:

```
print([list(x) for x in df.to_records(index=True)])
#[[0, 1, 2], [1, 3, 4], [2, 5, 6]]
```